# how to give variable into window.location

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have a javascript which I need to give a variable. I cannot figure it out, it is not working. Anyone that can help ?

Thanks

```
window.location('<?php echo "edit_expedite.php?id=$id"?>');
```

Comment: where's the document ready function?

Comment: Check in console for error and add it here.

Comment: look at the view source, what it have printed from php? And post complete code so chaps at SO knows what you are trying to achieve

Comment: it's just like, `location = '<?php echo "edit_expedite.php?id=$id";?>';`

Comment: @marios check the answer and say what transpired

Comment: when I check the source code I see this. window.location('edit_expedite.php?id='+"2118");

This is correct, only when I click, it goes to the first id in table, and that is 2101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.location('edit_expedite.php?id='+"<?php echo $id; ?>");`

Comment: window.location('edit_expedite.php?id='+"<?php echo $id; ?>");

This one is working for me, however, this script is in a while loop, but it is not taking the id which it need to be. It take the first id from my MySQL table. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can not just accept but can upvote as well.  :) Anyways thanks i could be of help to you @Marios

Comment: I want to do upvote but I get the message that I need first 15 reputation points :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
<script>
   window.location.href = "<?= 'edit_expedite.php?id='.$id ?>";
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables inside single quotes are not parsed.

They are parsed in double quotes.

Instead of mixing single and double quotes, we will make it simple.

Construct whole url in a PHP variable and print that variable.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
$id = 2423;
$urlTo = 'edit_expedite.php?id=' . $id;
echo "<script>window.location('".$urlTo."')<script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script>
    window.location.href = 'edit_expedite.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**there are several ways to send data from PHP to JAVASCRIPT
you are using the easiest one.
 you are using non function as a function
you have to assign the window.location as :**

```
window.location.assign("<?php echo "edit_expedite.php?id=$id"; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location('edit_expedite.php?id='+"<?php echo $id; ?>");
```

This one is working for me, however, this script is in a while loop, but it is not taking the id which it need to be. It take the first id from my MySQL table. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    trigger: 'left',

    items: {

  "Edit expedite": {
    name: "Edit expedite", 
    icon: "paste",callback: function(key, options) {
      // Do your page redirection here.
      window.location('edit_expedite.php?id='+"<?php echo $rij["id"]; ?>");
 }},
 }
});
```

});

This is the code where the ID need to be selected from MYSQL.